# define a function use other function names as parameter

Tags: python, pandas, function, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have a DataFrame looks like below:

```
df = {'col_1': [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10],
      'col_2': [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10],
      'col_3':['A','A','A','A','A','B','B','B','B','B']}
df = pd.DataFrame(df)
```

while the real data I'm using has hundreds of columns, I want to manipulate these columns using different functions like `min`,`max`  as well as self-defined function like:

```
def dist(x):
    return max(x) - min(x)
def HHI(x):
    ss = sum([s**2 for s in x])
    return ss
```

Instead of wirting many lines, I want to have a function like :

```
def myfunc(cols,fun):
    return df.groupby('col_3')[[cols]].transform(lambda x: fun)
# which allow me to do something like:

df[['min_' + s for s in cols]] = myfunc(cols, min)
df[['max_' + s for s in cols]] = myfunc(cols, max)
df[['dist_' + s for s in cols]] = myfunc(cols, dist)
```

**Is this possible in Python(my guess is 'yes')?

Then how if yes?**

**EDIT ====== ABOUT NAME OF SELF-DEFINED FUNCTION =======**
According to `jpp`'s solution, what I've asked is possible, at least for bulit-in functions, more work need regard self-defined function.

A workable solution,

```
temp = df.copy()
for func in ['HHI','DIST'] :
    print(func)
    temp[[ func + s for s in cols]] = df.pipe(myfunc,cols,eval(func))
```

The key here is to use `eval` tunction to convert string expression as a function. However, there may be better way to do this, looking forward to see.

**EDIT ====== per jpp's comment about name of self-defined function =======**

jpp's comment that feeds function name directly to `myfun` is valid based on my test, however, new column name based on `func` will be some thing like: `<function HHI at 0x00000194460019D8>`, which is not very readable, the modification is `temp[[ str(func.__name__) + s for s in cols]]`, hope this will help those who come to this problem later.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's one way using [`pd.DataFrame.pipe`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.pipe.html).

With Python *everything* is an object and can be passed around with no type-checking. The philosophy is "Don't check if it works, just try it...". Hence you can pass either a string or a function to `myfunc` and thereon to [`transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.transform.html) without any harmful side-effects.

```
def myfunc(df, cols, fun):
    return df.groupby('col_3')[cols].transform(fun)

cols = ['col_1', 'col_2']

df[[f'min_{s}' for s in cols]] = df.pipe(myfunc, cols, 'min')
df[[f'max_{s}' for s in cols]] = df.pipe(myfunc, cols, 'max')
df[[f'dist_{s}' s in cols]] = df.pipe(myfunc, cols, lambda x: x.max() - x.min())
```

Result:

```
print(df)

   col_1  col_2 col_3  min_col_1  min_col_2  max_col_1  max_col_2  dist_col_1  \
0      1      1     A          1          1          5          5           4   
1      2      2     A          1          1          5          5           4   
2      3      3     A          1          1          5          5           4   
3      4      4     A          1          1          5          5           4   
4      5      5     A          1          1          5          5           4   
5      6      6     B          6          6         10         10           4   
6      7      7     B          6          6         10         10           4   
7      8      8     B          6          6         10         10           4   
8      9      9     B          6          6         10         10           4   
9     10     10     B          6          6         10         10           4   

   dist_col_2  
0           4  
1           4  
2           4  
3           4  
4           4  
5           4  
6           4  
7           4  
8           4  
9           4
```

Comment: thanks, your solution works, really nice about `pipe` and `f'min_{s}'`, new thing to learn.

Comment: @JasonGoal, Yes, f-strings are available in Python 3.6+ and are more efficient than manual string concatenation. `pipe` should be used more often in my opinion, it makes code cleaner and clearer.

Comment: yes, you are onto the point, that's why I'm always looking for one-liner solution, though I'm still not good at it.

Comment: Hi @jpp, just found out that if I really want to use `df.pipe(myfunc, cols, 'dist')`, where `dist` is the name of self-defined function, an error is thrown out `AttributeError: 'DataFrameGroupBy' object has no attribute 'dist'`, is there a workaround which allows me to use just the name of a self-defined function?

Comment: @JasonGoal, Don't use a string here. Feed `dist` in directly, i.e. `df.pipe(myfunc, cols, dist)`. The point is you can use a string or function **as appropriate**.

Comment: I tested your suggestion, it worked.  `temp[[ str(func.__name__) + s for s in cols]]` will produce a readable new column name by the way.

Answer (score 3):

yes, you're very close:

```
def myfunc(cols,fun):
    return df.groupby('col_3')[cols].transform(lambda x: fun(x))
```

Or:

```
def myfunc(cols,fun):
    return df.groupby('col_3')[cols].transform(fun)
```

Comment: thanks both of your solutions work like a charm. I know this Python and SO will never let me down, thanks very much guys. I'll take `jpp's` as the answer for extra `pipe` thing and `f'min_{s}'` to create a new list of strings.

Comment: @JasonGoal, happy to help,  and yes jpp's suggestion of using `pipe` is a great idea.